# Call .php file with an ajax request - wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to call a php file from an ajax request in wordpress. The problem I am encountering is that the ajax request requires a path to the php file. I am unsure of where to place this php file in my wordpress installation. Further, this file cannot be included inline because I need to call this php file only when the user decides to call it. I don't use jquery right now but would be open to using it as I'm pretty sure that's client side only so the server wouldn't have to be involved.

As an example of something I would like to do let's try this with a form. This example was taken from `http://thisinterestsme.com/ajax-form-submission-php/`.

I would include this in the webpage.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Example Ajax PHP Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form id="my_form_id">
            Your Email Address: <input type="text" id="email" /><br>
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>

        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#my_form_id').on('submit', function(e){
                    //Stop the form from submitting itself to the server.
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var email = $('#email').val();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: 'submission.php',
                        data: {email: email},
                        success: function(data){
                            alert(data);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then elsewhere on the server I would have this file. The problem is I don't know where to place this file or what path to give the ajax request above.

```
<?php
$emailAddress = false;
if(isset($_POST['email'])){
    $emailAddress = $_POST['email'];
}

echo 'Received email was: ' . $emailAddress;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have this php:

```
<?php
 $emailAddress = false;
 if(isset($_POST['email'])){
    $emailAddress = $_POST['email'];
 }

 echo 'Received email was: ' . $emailAddress;
?>
```

You should name this file as page-submission.php and save it where your functions.php is located, then create a blank page name "submission". You can now then call this file in your ajax as /submission.

Here's the visual hierarchy how it works:

[image]

Comment: What if I want to use multiple php files? This method does not work anyway.

Comment: pay attention to the orange box that is labeled page-$slug.php
I guess I should add to the instruction that to set/use the page/post title in the permalinks settings.
This is the method that I use all the time and prevented me in polluting the functions.php

Comment: I don't know enough about wordpress to make these modifications. Can you further elaborate?

Comment: Do these steps:
1) create a page-example.php
put this code in it:
<?php 
  echo 'This is page-example.php';
2) Create a blank page in the wordpress admin and give it a title: "example", then publish it.
3) In Admin page, go to Settings > Permalinks, then choose the "Post Name", save your changes.
4) Then copy and paste this to then url box:
http://thisinterestsme.com/example  (if your .htaccess is configured correctly)
http://thisinterestsme.com/index.php/example  (if your .htaccess needed configuration)
Either way, you should see the page with text: "This is page-example.php"

Comment: I followed you up to step 4. I am unsure of what to actually do with that URL. What "URL Box" are you talking about? That was a website I just used as an example, I don't actually own that site.

Comment: The goal of step 4 is to see the echo "This is page-example.php" in your browser... if you successfully see that, it means you can put whatever code in page-example.php and call it via ajax.... and it doesn't matter if that URL is just an example... since you've used it in your sample code, I used that URL for consistency. You can use the wordpress url that you're working on.

Comment: thank you I was able to get that to work. Now, back to my original question, how do I call this with an ajax request? I modified my original code posted in the question to have the url line `page-example.php' but upon hitting submit it just refreshes the page. I also tried `example.php` and `example`. Is there some path I need to set up correctly?

Comment: whatever url you put in the browser to hit page-example.php that what you'll use on your ajax.

Answer (score 1):

You can add PHP functions to your `functions.php` file which can be easily executed from ajax:

```
function post_email_address(WP_REST_Request $request){
  return 'Received email was: ' . $request['email'];
}

add_action('rest_api_init', function(){
  register_rest_route( 'foo/v1', '/postEmail', array(
    'methods' => 'POST',
    'callback' => 'post_email_address',
  ));
});
```

Then in your front end:

```
  $(function(){
    $('#my_form_id').submit(function(e){
      //Stop the form from submitting itself to the server.
      e.preventDefault();
      var email = $('#email').val();
      $.post("/wp-json/foo/v1/postEmail", {
        email: email
      },function(data){
        console.log(data);
      });
    });
  });
```

"foo" is the namespace, you could use something more relevant to your app.

Comment: I am unable to trigger the script still. I did exactly what you said with the php (also fixed the syntax error in the last line) and I put the ajax inside script tags on the frontend and left the form. When I hit submit there is a page reload and nothing happens.

Comment: are you sure your `document.ready` function is running? ie. can you log to the console from there and see it?  Might try changing `$(document).ready(function(){` to `$(function(){`.  Are you also able to log from the `onSubmit` function and see it before the page reloads?

Comment: actually just change the `.on('submit'` to `$('#my_form_id').submit(function(e){`

Comment: I tried doing what you said but I am unsure if I did it correctly. The php remained the same. https://pastebin.com/VDyNRt2i

Comment: man i am sorry I am trying everything but I cant get it working either. will update if I can

Comment: @frillybob Check out the edits! I tested and have this working! I used the docs for WP rest API: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/

Comment: I was still unable to get this working. How are you triggering the script? With the form example I had in my original post? On page load with no HTML form I don't see how this would work either as there is nowhere to get the data from yet. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I had it in the submit function of the form

Comment: I have added `onsubmit="callF():"` in the header of the form and enclosed the javascript in source tags and a function called `callF(){...}`. The page just reloads and does nothing else.

Comment: Thanks again but I'm still not able to get it to work. I must be missing something simple at this point. I tried inserting an alert in the javascript code  but it does not trigger. What am I doing wrong? Are you using jquery with the `$` signs? I tried including that in the head but it also does not work. https://pastebin.com/ug4EzCc4